# Passing Arguments to ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

```
public class start implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aL) {
      method(arguments);

    }
  }

method(arguments) {
   //stuff
}
```

I want a JButton to tell the program to start a method using the arguments "stuff" So I put the actionListener above on the button however the actionListener does not have access to the arguments and I don't know how to give it them (I looked at the oracle docs and couldn't figure it out). I tried this:

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent aL, stuff) {
```

and that doesn't work, I get the error

```
Compute.java:45: error: Compute.start is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
  public class start implements ActionListener {
         ^
```

And I tried putting an @Override but you can't override that according to the compiler. So, how can I give the arguments to the ActionListener or have the method outside of the button but only start working once the button is pressed, however I am using a JProgressBar within the JFrame the button is in which uses the method as it's timer thing so it would be preferable to pass the arguments to the actionListener

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You may want to try posting your code as a [mcve]

Comment: This kind of stuff is OOP 101 that should be sorted out long before attempting GUIs..

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the arguments by constructor. But of course it means with this way you can pass the arguments only when creating the `ActionListener`.

```
public class Start implements ActionListener {

    SomeType arguments;
    public Start (SomeType arguments) {
         this.arguments = arguments;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aL) {
        method(arguments);    
    }
}
```